# Insert 'Dummy Rows' In SQL with aggregate functions

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that includes the following fields:

Company
fruit
date
qty
price
total_price

I have a query that summarizes the data:

```
SELECT
company,
extract(year from date) as year,
case
    when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) <= 3
        THEN 'Q1'
    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) BETWEEN 4 AND 6
        THEN 'Q2'
    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) BETWEEN 7 AND 9
        THEN 'Q3'
    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) BETWEEN 10 AND 12
        THEN 'Q4'
    ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
END AS QUARTER,
COUNT(*) AS purchases,
SUM(QTY) AS total_fruit_purchased,
SUM(total_price) AS COMISSION 
FROM fees.fruit_paid
where extract(year from date) >= 2015
            GROUP BY
                company,
                extract(year from date),
                case
                    when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) <= 3
                        THEN 'Q1'
                    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) BETWEEN 4 AND 6
                        THEN 'Q2'
                    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) BETWEEN 7 AND 9
                        THEN 'Q3'
                    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) BETWEEN 10 AND 12
                        THEN 'Q4'
                    ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
                END
                    ORDER BY
                        company,
                        YEAR,
                        QUARTER
```

How would I go about including dummy rows into the output if there is no data for a certain company for a year & quarter in my time frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little complicated, so let me step you through it. First, you need a list of companies, including companies that don't have purchases. You can get that with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT company
FROM fruit_paid;
```

And you could just use that to get a summary for all companies and all time, with something like this:

```
WITH
  company_names as
    (SELECT DISTINCT company
     FROM fruit_paid)

SELECT company_names.company, sum(fruit_paid.qty) as total_fruit_purchased
FROM company_names
  LEFT OUTER JOIN fruit_paid
    ON company_names.company = fruit_paid.company
GROUP BY company_names.company;
```

Two things going on there: 1- I'm taking the earlier query ("`SELECT DISTINCT ...`"), and making it something called a common table expression -- it just means I can use that query like a table. 2- I'm using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which will use the left table to define the rows, and join in everything from the right table where it can.

That's the core of what's needed to get this done. You can get a list of years with the `generate_series` function. Something like:

```
SELECT extract(YEAR from generate_series) as year
FROM generate_series('2015-01-01'::date,
                     '2016-01-01'::date,
                     '1 year');
```

That you can turn around and add to the previous query:

```
WITH
  company_names as
    (SELECT DISTINCT company
     FROM fruit_paid),
  years as
    (SELECT extract(YEAR from generate_series) as year
     FROM generate_series('2015-01-01'::date,
                          '2016-01-01'::date,
                          '1 year'))

SELECT company_names.company,
       years.year,
       sum(fruit_paid.qty) as total_fruit_purchased
FROM company_names
  CROSS JOIN years
  LEFT OUTER JOIN fruit_paid
    ON company_names.company = fruit_paid.company
    AND extract(YEAR from fruit_paid.date) = years.year
GROUP BY company_names.company, years.year;
```

Using a `CROSS JOIN` there gets you one row per combination of the left table (`company_names`) and the right table (`years`). In other words, one row for each company and year, regardless of purchases. That you left join with fruit_paid again to get the purchase data.

The last piece is the quarters. There's an easy way to get a list of all quarters:

```
VALUES ('Q1'), ('Q2'), ('Q3'), ('Q4');
```

So let's add that in:

```
WITH
  company_names as
    (SELECT DISTINCT company
     FROM fruit_paid),
  years as
    (SELECT extract(YEAR from generate_series) as year
     FROM generate_series('2015-01-01'::date,
                          '2016-01-01'::date,
                          '1 year')),
  quarters (quarter) as
    (VALUES ('Q1'), ('Q2'), ('Q3'), ('Q4'))

SELECT company_names.company,
       years.year,
       quarters.quarter,
       sum(fruit_paid.qty) as total_fruit_purchased
FROM company_names
  CROSS JOIN years
  CROSS JOIN quarters
  LEFT OUTER JOIN fruit_paid
    ON company_names.company = fruit_paid.company
    AND extract(YEAR from fruit_paid.date) = years.year
    AND quarters.quarter = case
                             WHEN extract(MONTH FROM date) <= 3
                               THEN 'Q1'
                             WHEN extract(MONTH FROM date) BETWEEN 4 AND 6
                               THEN 'Q2'
                             WHEN extract(MONTH FROM date) BETWEEN 7 AND 9
                               THEN 'Q3'
                             WHEN extract(MONTH FROM date) BETWEEN 10 AND 12
                               THEN 'Q4'
                             ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
                           END
GROUP BY company_names.company, years.year, quarters.quarter;
```

The only fancy new thing we did here was give a bit more definition for the `quarters` common table expression -- we added a column name. For pseudo-queries like `VALUES`, it can be handy to be able to define the names for the columns returned, and it makes the query a bit more understandable later (otherwise we'd be joining on `quarters.column`, which is just tough to understand).

Hope that helps.

Here's some of the relevant documentation:

- [Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html), which goes over using query results as tables, and also touches on the different join types.
- [WITH queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html), which specifically talks about common table expressions.
- [VALUES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-values.html), which I include for completeness.
- [Set-Returning Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html), which describes all of the ways to use `generate_series`.